# Decision Tree Classifier to predict the future

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

how can I use this model to predict something in the future, that is not included in my data set?! 2021-09-03 is for example not included and I want to predict it, if it will be 1 "up" oder 0 "down"

My Code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from google.colab import files
files.upload()

df = pd.read_csv('HistoricalPrices.csv')

df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date'].values))
df.index.name = 'Date'
df

df['Price_Up'] = np.where(df[' Close'].shift(-1) > df[' Close'], 0,1)
df =df.drop(columns=['Date'])
df

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size= 0.1)

tree = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X_train, Y_train)
print(tree.score(X_test, Y_test))

tree_predictions = tree.predict(X_test)
print(tree_predictions)

Y_test
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrZw9.png)

(This is a pic of my data set)

Comment: This is a time series problem. LSTM is generally used for this thing.

Comment: Could you show me how to overcome this problem in a simple way? please

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to predict the future prices. But you just want to predict 1 or 0. Just subtract `open` from `close` and if the answer is positive, then it's 1 else 0. No need of machine learning!

Comment: I guess you got me wrong sir. (Sorry my english is bad) I want to predict the future direction "1" for up and "0" for down.  e.g. 03-09-2021 is not encluded in my data set. I want to get a one or zero for this day in the future!

Comment: take a look at the linked pic to see my dataset

Comment: Oh, then use LSTM. Read this [article](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/11/keras-long-short-term-memory-lstm-model-predict-stock-prices.html#:~:text=(%2018%3An45%20)-,Using%20a%20Keras%20Long%20Short%2DTerm%20Memory%20(LSTM),Model%20to%20Predict%20Stock%20Prices&text=LSTMs%20are%20very%20powerful%20in,in%20predicting%20its%20future%20price.). It will give you some idea on how to solve this problem.